# Catalog of all Windows 10 gestures (tablet mode)

Tags: windows-10, tablet, gestures

Is there any list of *ALL* the gestures available in Windows 10 tablet mode? I mean gestures to perform on the tablet screen itself, not on a trackpad or whatever.

I haven't been able to find it.

Answer (score 0):

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/use-touch-with-windows-528db542-4b34-3120-2a87-6e0bfbe95abb

Some of the basic gestures are found here

https://winaero.com/list-touch-gestures-windows-10/

Complete list here

Comment: @EthanOBrien I knew the second link you mention. I thought it was not an actual full list. :/

Comment: Answers that contain only links are not allowed.  These two links appear on a typical search for Windows Gestures on Google Search.  We are looking for content to be contained within the answer itself with external links only being used as a source or citation.